# PHP MySQL How to skip displaying a field

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, field, skip

I have the table MYTABLE that contains the fields: ID, PASSWORD, COL1, COL2, COL3, DATE
I would like to fetch and display all records in an html table but skipping ID and PASSWORD fields...
I'm using the following code which isn't working:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1";
$results = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<tr>";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    foreach ($r as $item) { 
        // let's not display ID and password
        if ($r == 'ID' || $r == 'PASSWORD') continue; // this is the line that I want to figure out 
    echo "<td>$item</td>";  
    } // end for loop
} // end while  
unset($item);
echo "</tr>";
```

Obviously there's more than 1 way to do it, for example I can replace the foreach loop with a for loop:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=6;$i++) {
    if ($i == 0 || $i == 1 ) continue;
    echo "<td>$r[$i]</td>";
} // end for
```

This will skip ID and PASSWORD fields but I don't want to use it, because I'm running the code on more than one table (table name is fetched from html select tag) and these tables may not have the same number of fields/columns (but they will always have ID and PASSWORD).

I can also do it with SQL statement (I don't want to), but then I'll have to query into a temp, drop the ID,PASSWORD columns and then fetch from the temp table. (by the way is there a compelling reason as to why I SHOULD in fact do it with SQL rathen than PHP?)

Comment: Why can't you just use "select COL1, COL2, COL3, DATE from MYTABLE" ?

Comment: Because he sad: "This will skip ID and PASSWORD fields but I don't want to use it, because I'm running the code on more than one table (table name is fetched from html select tag)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1";
$results = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<tr>";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    foreach ($r as $key => $item) { 
        // let's not display ID and password
        if (!in_array($key, array('PASSWORD', 'ID'))) {
            echo "<td>$item</td>";  
        }
    } // end for loop
} // end while  
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: I almost forgot about in_array. Thanks you very much, I'm going this solution.

Comment: The key was not the in_array, i am just using this to not make OR operator. The point of this was the $r as $key => $item.

Comment: Oh yes i agree mate, it was the $r as $k=>$item. I was only side noting the in_array usage. Again, thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($r as $k => $item) { 
    // let's not display ID and password
    if ($k == 'ID' || $k == 'PASSWORD') continue;
    echo "<td>$item</td>";  
}
```

This meets exactly your request.
I hope this result now useful to you, and after that, you evolve from it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do it this way:

```
$query = "SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, DATE FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, but like I said I shouldn't do it with SQL since: 1. the real table has more than 24 fields/cols 2. There are many tables and they do not have an equal amount of fields

Comment: Sorry, I must've read to fast, thought you only wanted to re-use the loop. Luckily you got more answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let it easy..

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT  COL1, COL2, COL3, DATE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ..whatever..";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row["COL1"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["COL2"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["COL3"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["DATA"]."</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Can't do that. There's more than one table and they don't have an equal number of fields, nor their fields have the same names (except ID and PASSWORD). Thanks for the answer.